# Check variable's content in popup.js - variable is gotten from background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have in `background.js` a variable

```
var currentHost = "";
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active' : true, 'currentWindow': true}, function(tabs){
        let newUrl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
        currentHost = newUrl.host;
}
```

Then i transfer this variable to `popup.js` with

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
        var currentHost = bg.currentHost;
...
}
```

Now i want check the content of the variable `currentHost` in `popup.js`, with `console.log(currentHost)` (on the place of `...`) but get `undefined` under all circumstances.

What i'm doing wrong? How i can check this kind of variable?

[background.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qNREq5WbMWfvyVEZz9BjxHBFvVhC1eHU), [popup.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kWqOgPknMCY9ztxa0cYclvYHLZ1Dplyh)

**PS**: got it finally through simple adding of "background" to manifest permissions.

Comment: Your onUpdated code assumes only the active tab gets updated, but it's not true: all tabs can be updated. There's no need for query() at all, simply use `tab.url` as you already have that parameter. Anyway this entire approach doesn't seem useful because **any** tab can be updated at any time including when it changes its title or favicon or muted state and so on. You can probably remove all of this and simply call chrome.tabs.query in the popup.

Comment: i can't really extrapolate a practial approach from your recommendation - partly because there are a bit more things are depending from the example code, partly because i don't have enough practice. Could you take a look into attached files make a less cryptic recommendation? I've tried one to one your code, but got just a bunch of errors.